# Function of two variables is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

> A function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be **differentiable** at $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}$ if there exists a linear transformation $\lambda$ so that $$\displaystyle\lim_{\xi \to 0} \frac{\|f(x_0+h_1,y_0+h_2) - f(x_0,y_0) - \lambda(h,k)\|}{\|\xi\|} = 0 \hspace{1cm} \xi=(h,k) \to 0$$

**Solution Verification Requested**

Let $f(x,y) = (x+y)^2 = x^2+2xy+y^2$ and we want to check differentiability at $(2,3)$

First, we examine just the numerator and forget the other details for a moment. We examine

$$f(2+h,3+k) - f(2,3)-\lambda(h,k)$$

$$= (2+h)^2+2(2+h)(3+k)+(3+k)^2 - 25 - \lambda(h,k)$$

$$= h^2+4h+4+k^2+6k+9+12+4k+6h+2hk -25 - \lambda(h,k)$$

$$= h^2+2hk+k^2+(10h+10k)+(25 -25) - \lambda(h,k)$$

$$h^2+2hk+k^2+(10h+10k) - \lambda(h,k)$$

Choose $\lambda(h,k) = 10h+10k$. So then we have

$$h^2+2hk+k^2 +10h_10k - \lambda(h,k) = h^2+2hk+k^2=(h+k)^2$$

Now, we can observe that

$$\displaystyle\lim_{\xi \to 0} \frac{\|f(2+h,3+k)-f(2,3)-\lambda(h,k)\|}{\|\xi\|} = \displaystyle\lim_{\xi \to 0} \frac{(h+k)^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

$$\leq \displaystyle\lim_{\xi \to 0} \Big( \frac{|h|^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} + \frac{|k|^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} \Big) = \displaystyle\lim_{\xi \to 0} \frac{|h|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}|h| + \displaystyle\lim_{\xi \to 0} \frac{|k|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}|k| = 0+0 = 0$$

Thus, $f$ is differentiable at $(2,3)$

Does this look good? Did I wave hands anywhere?

Comment: Looks good. You can check the answer by just evaluating the partials and checking that the coincide with $\lambda$.

Comment: @copper.hat oh? I’m not familiar with this method. Is there anywhere I can read up on that?

Comment: It follows by restricting the $\xi \to 0$ to going along each axis.

Comment: @copper.hat oh so you’re saying if the sum of the partials equals lambda, then we’re good

Comment: I mean that $\lambda (a,b) = {\partial f(x,y) \over x} a +  {\partial f(x,y) \over y} b$. I just meant that it could be used as a quick check.